# "Fault: Response has already started" error in Elsa Workflow dotnet core

Tags: http, .net-core, elsa-workflows

I am working with elsa workflow framework in dotnet core. The first two steps in the workflow work fine. However in the third step, I am getting the error displayed in [image: this] image ""Fault: Response has already started"". The sample flowchart image is [image: this one]. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a response has already started. There are many reasons I can think of that would cause this, but from looking at your workflow, it's hard to see why.

One reason could be that you have multiple workflow instances in the system that are somehow being resumed at the same time. This happens when a workflow isn't correlated, and the signal being received triggers all of them. This would cause multiple attempts to write an HTTP response.

Another reason could be that there's a bug in Elsa 1. For that, you could submit an issue on GitHub with steps to reproduce the problem.

However, Elsa 1 is no longer being maintained, so you might want to consider migrating to Elsa 2.

Alternatively, if you (have to) stay with Elsa 1, you might consider cloning the source code and reference the projects directly and use the debugger to set breakpoints at various places to see where and why an HTTP response is started. This way, you are bound to find out that an HTTP response is written (could be a simple status code that is being set) from at least two places during the same request.